# sed command to append different text at multiple occurrence of string

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

I want to use sed command to append text at multiple occurrence of string.

For Ex:

```
Hello world
types="program"
Mario
types="Game"
Hello world
types="program"
Mario
types="Game"
```

So at first occurrence of Mario i want to append 'firstMario' and at next occurrence 'secondMario', and so on.
OutPut:

```
Hello world
types="program"
firstMario
types="Game"
Hello world
types="program"
secondMario
types="Game"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '
  /Mario/{
    s//first&/
    :1
      n
      s//second&/
    b1
  }'
```

Or:

```
sed '
  1 {
    x;s/^/first/;x
  }
  /Mario/ {
    G
    s/\(Mario.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\1/
    x;s/second/third/;s/first/second/;x
  }'
```

Though to allow more than one Mario per line and generalize to more substitutions, I'd use `perl` instead:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{@words=qw(first second third)}
          s/(?=Mario)/$words[$n++]/ge'
```

Comment: With unknown input (unknown no. of occurrences) one could use perl module [Lingua::EN::Numbers](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-EN-Numbers/lib/Lingua/EN/Numbers.pm)

Answer (score 0):

You will have a hard time using "first second third ..." in an automated way, since they are not described anywhere (at least there is no standard tool). I'll give a solution with integers:

```
n=$( grep -c '^Mario$' file )
for (( i=1 ; i<=$n ; i++ )) ; do
  sed -i "1,/^Mario$/s/^Mario$/$i&/" file
done
```

output:

```
Hello world
types="program"
1Mario
types="Game"
Hello world
types="program"
2Mario
types="Game"
```